# Family of quartic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that contain a fixed line or conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension 4 and $\mathbb{P}^3=\mathbb{P}(V)$. The space of quartic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is $\mathbb{P}(\text{Sym}^4(V^*))$ and the dimension of this space is equal to 34. It is not hard to compute the dimension of the spase of those quartics that contain a fixed line $L$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Indeed, we can suppose that in the coordinates $[x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3]$ this line is given by $L=\{x_2=x_3=0\}$. Then the quartic which contains $L$ doesn't have terms $x_{0}^4, x_{1}^4, x_{0}^3x_{1}, x_0^2x_1^2, x_0x_1^3$ and thus the dimension of the space of such quartics is equal to 29. Hence the dimension of the family of those quartics surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that contain a line is equal to 29+4=33.

My question is, how to rewrite this using the language of sheaves?

Namely, suppose we have a fixed line $L$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$. How to describe the space of all quartics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that contain $L$ as a projectivization of the space of global sections of certain coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Same question for quartics that contain fixed conic.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this argument is not rigorous?

Comment: Actually, it is and the word "rigorous" is not quite appropriate. I have made an edit.

Comment: OK. The motiviation to do this is still not so clear to me, but anyway"  the sheaf you want is $\mathcal I_L \otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^3}(4)$ where $\mathcal I_L$ is the ideal sheaf of the line. Then you can use the ideal sheaf sequence for $\mathcal I_L$ to get your answer. The same approach works for a conic too.